# A generic type object that surrounds every field with an Observable

Tags: typescript, generics

I don't even know how to explain this properly with a title.

Take this interface for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
```

I need a type/interface (let's call it `ObjectToObservables` here) that would perform the same as this:

```
interface ObjectToObservables {
  a: Observable<string>;
  b: Observable<number>;
}
```

And I want it to be defined automatically like `ObjectToObservables<MyInterface>`, because I don't want to just hard-type both of these. This can probably be useful with other types as well, besides Observables.

It this possible to accomplish in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this type by enumerating all properties and changing their type:

```js
type ObservableObject<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: Observable<T[K]> }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=79&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8yA3gLABQAvvfWAJ4AOKG2UehEGAFYQEYMsggAPSCAAmmZAHt0w0ZQC81ZAG0A0slDIA1hFaKYyUgF0AXGiy58RMnquUmdZnVCRYiFACyrACS4NDwSNT0yDHIcHaYYFCgAOYA3NGx6HYgAK4AtujQGYxeZXRsnPY8fEShvhEomtyO-EIiYkH14f7kaUA)

[image: example]

Comment: thank you, can you please link to documentation that explains this? I don't know why this can't be an interface of why you have to write `extends object`

Comment: @Tovar you can go through the entire documentation on creating types from other types in typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html